# Phpnative response writer in Solr 4.0?

Tags: php, solr

I'm using Solr 4.0 with php extension (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) and trying to enable 'phpnative' response writer. After dropping the jar file (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1967) to %SOLR_HOME%/lib and adding the line `<queryResponseWriter name="phpnative" class="solr.PHPNativeResponseWriter">` to solrconfig.xml, the solr process doesn't run. Here's the log:

```
       Mar 21, 2012 3:23:24 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore initWriters
INFO: created json: solr.JSONResponseWriter
Mar 21, 2012 3:23:24 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/request/QueryResponseWriter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:314)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:403)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:400)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createQueryResponseWriter(SolrCore.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initWriters(SolrCore.java:1568)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:566)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:504)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:655)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:409)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:294)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:93)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.request.QueryResponseWriter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 52 more

Mar 21, 2012 3:23:24 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
SEVERE: Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logsMar 21, 2012 3:23:24 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore initWriters
INFO: created json: solr.JSONResponseWriter
Mar 21, 2012 3:23:24 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/request/QueryResponseWriter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:314)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:403)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:400)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createQueryResponseWriter(SolrCore.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initWriters(SolrCore.java:1568)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:566)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:504)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:655)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:409)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:294)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:93)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.request.QueryResponseWriter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 52 more

Mar 21, 2012 3:23:24 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
SEVERE: Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SOLR-1967](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1967) issue  is almost 2 years old and the jar you're using is not meant to be used with Solr 4.x. In fact, the [`QueryResponseWriter`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/response/QueryResponseWriter.java) interface has been moved to the `org.apache.solr.response` package. You have two options:

- trying to get it working with Solr 3.x (not sure if it'll work out of the box with 3.5)
- trying to integrate the source code attached to the patch within the Solr trunk, adapting and fixing the errors you find